# HistogramList for DateHistogram?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, date-and-time, histograms

`HistogramList` and `Histogram` are closely related:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];
bSpec = {1};

{
 BarChart[Last[HistogramList[data, bSpec]]], 
 Histogram[data, bSpec]
}
```

[image]

`DateHistogram` is more like a black box with respect to that:

```
dates = AbsoluteTime /@  RandomChoice[DateRange[{2010, 1, 1}, {2010, 5, 31}, "Day"], 200];
 bSpec = "Month";


{
 BarChart[Last[HistogramList[dates, bSpec]]], 
 DateHistogram[dates, bSpec]
}
```

[image]

One could do

```
Reap[DateHistogram[dates, "Month", (Sow[{##}]; #2) &]][[2, 1, 1]]
```

> ```
>  {{{3471292800, 3473971200}, {3473971200, 3476390400}, {3476390400,
> ```
>
> 3479068800}, {3479068800, 3481660800}, {3481660800, 
>      3484339200}}, {29, 29, 42, 47, 53}}

```
BarChart @ Last @ %
```

[image]

And tweak it but it is not pretty/efficient.

#### Question

Is there a better way to get `HistogramList` for dates based data? Compatible with `DateHistogram`?

Comment: `"Month"` is not a valid bin specification for `HistogramList` so you are getting the `Automatic` setting. You would need to create a *bin function* that would give a date (maybe `AbsoluteTime`) partition of the dates for `HistogramList`.

Comment: @Edmund The point is I don't want to because this is already done. DateHistogram uses it. Would be also nice to know what Month means.

Answer (score 7):

```
dates = AbsoluteTime /@  RandomChoice[DateRange[{2010, 1, 1}, {2010, 5, 31}, "Day"], 200];
bSpec = "Month";
```

Didn't have time to dig deeper so it may be limited but it suits my needs atm.

Keep in mind that it is an undocumented function:

```
binSpec = System`TimeVisualizationsDump`dateHistogramBinning[
  dates,
  bSpec,
  Identity, (*smoothing function - at least the pattern name says so*)
  $TimeZone
  ]

hlist = HistogramList[dates, binSpec ];

{
  BarChart[
     #2, ChartLabels -> (DateString[#, "MonthNameShort"] & /@ #)
  ] & @@  hlist
  ,
  DateHistogram[dates, bSpec]
}
```

[image]

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thank you so much.

Comment: @masterxilo long time no see. Thanks but that is an overreaction ;-)

Comment: Mathematica has varying levels of applicability to the projects that come my way, but it always feels good to come back to this competent community of experts like yourself ;)