# Generic way for Dynamic style Directives in Histogram or DateHistogram

Tags: plotting, dynamic, options, histograms

Let's say I have two samples:

```
data1 = RandomChoice[DateRange[{2010, 1, 1}, {2010, 4, 31}, "Day"], 100];
data2 = RandomChoice[DateRange[{2010, 5, 1}, {2010, 8, 31}, "Day"], 100];
```

I want to plot a histogram with both of them, and I want `data2's` bars to have `Dotted` or `Dashed` `EdgeForm` depending of a value of some variable, let's say `t`.

Problems with available styling options:

- `Dynamic @ DateHistogram[...]`, recreating it will be too slow for bigger samples.
- `ChartStyle` can't be `Dynamic` or contain it in a list. It can have `Directives` but they can't contain `Dynamic` either so it won't work as a wrapper.
- `ChartElementFunction` does not allow to distinguish data samples.
- `Histogram*` allows certain wrappers for data, e.g. `Style`: `Style[data2, Orange]` but it won't allow `Dynamic` inside

The only way I was able to use is a hairy postprocessing:

```
t = True; Checkbox @ Dynamic @ t

DateHistogram[
    {data1, data2}, ChartStyle -> {Green, Red} 
] /. d_Directive :> Which[
   MemberQ[d, Red, ∞], 
   Dynamic[
     Directive[##, EdgeForm[If[TrueQ[t], Dashed, Dotted]]]
   ] & @@ d
   ,
   True, 
   d
]
```

[image]

Is there a more stable/generic way to achieve this?

Comment: Nested `Directive`s complicate post-processing too much. Why `Directive` isn't `Flat`?! I see no reason to keep nested structures of `Directive`s.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That is another question but can live with this.

Comment: Is `DateHistogram` (which I don't have) necessary for this example or could you be using a `Histogram` instead?

Comment: Sorry, I've got nothing.  Alexey's method looks good to me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard in case of `Histogram` I can use `HistogramList` to assemble `Graphics` by myself and have a full control. But for `DateHistogram` it is not possible :/ [HistogramList for DateHistogram?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123607/5478)

Answer (score 3):

#### A better post-processing approach

You can use `Annotation` (or `Hyperlink` or `Button`) as a wrapper for the data with a *tag* as the second argument for simplification of the post-processing:

```
DateHistogram[{data1, Annotation[data2, myTag]}] /. 
 Annotation[d_, myTag] :> Sequence[Dynamic[EdgeForm[If[TrueQ[t], Dashed, Dotted]]], d]
```

This is much simpler and more stable/generic than the method shown in the question, but it still depends on the specifics of the current implementation of `DateHistogram`.

---

#### A hackish solution

Another way is to fool the internal check for validness of style directives by wrapping the *tag* with `Glow` (other possibilities: `Specularity`, `RGBColor`, `Opacity`, `GrayLevel`; checked with *Mathematica* 11.0.0):

```
DateHistogram[{data1, data2}, ChartStyle -> {Green, Glow[myTag]}] /. 
 d_Directive /; MemberQ[d, Glow[myTag], ∞] :> 
  Sequence[d /. Glow[myTag] :> {}, Dynamic[EdgeForm[If[TrueQ[t], Dashed, Dotted]]]]
```

Shorter version:

```
DateHistogram[{data1, Style[data2, Glow[myTag]]}] /. 
 Directive[Glow[myTag]] :> Dynamic[EdgeForm[If[TrueQ[t], Dashed, Dotted]]]
```

Of course this method potentially can be broken in future if there will be introduced a check for validness of arguments of `Glow` etc. Hence the method shown in the previous section is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

#### A worse post-processing approach

I messed around with this for a while and this is the best I could do.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, 3], 100] & /@ {-1, 5};

t = True; Checkbox@Dynamic@t

MapAt[
  # /. _FEPrivate`If :> EdgeForm[If[t, Dashed, Dotted]] &,
  Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> {Green, Red}],
  {1, 1, 2, 2}
]
```

The second `2` in `{1, 1, 2, 2}` may be changed to target the styling.  Hey, I said it was worse. :^)

#### YAPPM

(Yet another post-processing method.) The same thing you did but less focused.

```
Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> {Green, Red}] /.
  x_Directive :> Dynamic[x] /. 
    x : Red :> {x, EdgeForm[If[t, Dashed, Dotted]]}
```

Comment: Look out for `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` too.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, I'm sure this is quite fragile. :-(

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for posting this answer! I won't upvote it but I express thanks because I was much wondered whether there is a straightforward way to solve this problem. Now I'm sure there is no way and the reason is clear: `Directive` doesn't accept `Dynamic` style directives. But WHY? I don't see any reason for this!

Comment: @Alexey I don't know; it doesn't seem to be easy to get an answer to [questions like that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118646/121).  I am glad you found something in this answer useful; I regularly find your answers quite enlightening.

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the low-level parameter of the Dashing:

```
t = Small;
Checkbox[Dynamic[t], {Small, 0}]
DateHistogram[{data1, 
  Style[data2, EdgeForm[Dashing[{Dynamic@t, Small}]]]}]
```

Comment: +1 Nice, sadly it is not general :(, e.g. controlling colors.

Comment: @Kuba not sure if I understand you correctly. `ChartStyle -> {Green, Red}` can still be added as an option for `DateHistogram`.

Comment: I meant to link it dynamically to e.g ColorSetter.

Answer (score 1):

You may apply `Dynamic` to the entire `DateHistogram`.

```
Checkbox[Dynamic@t, {Dashed, Dotted}]
```

Then

```
Dynamic@DateHistogram[{data1, data2}, 
  ChartStyle -> {Green, Directive@{Red, EdgeForm[t]}}]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 For simple cases it is a good solution I forgot to mention but I came here because it was not enough for large datasets. Recalculating whole plot takes to much time then.