# How to merger every three minutes values?

Tags: date-and-time

I have some date values like

```
date=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLINL.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

> `<|08:00:10->5,08:00:14->1,08:00:17->5,08:00:23->1,08:00:24->1,08:00:25->5,08:00:31->1,08:00:32->6,08:00:36->2,...|>`

Of course,the *hour* not always is `08` in my real case.I have a good method to merger the value for every ***one*** minute

```
GroupBy[Normal[date], StringDrop[Keys[#], -3] &, Total[<|#|>] &]
```

> `<|08:00->48,08:01->54,08:02->58,08:03->73,08:04->69,08:05->76,08:06->66,08:07->70,08:08->72,08:09->70,08:10->82,08:11->77,08:12->88,08:13->78,08:14->19|>`

But if I want to merger the value for every ***three*** minutes,is there any concise method to do this?

Comment: You could use `TimeSeries` but you have to define what does it mean to merge every three minutes.

Comment: @Kuba Such as 03:00 and 03:02 should regard one time.In my case,I get some 08:00,08:03,08:06,08:09,08:12,08:14..

Comment: Where should the 3minutes window start if the first value date is e.g: `08:04:10`.

Comment: @Kuba Like the function `BinLists`,we should give  a sort behavoir firstly..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this and let me know:

```
TimeSeriesAggregate[
   EventSeries @ date, {Quantity[3, "Minutes"], Left}, Total
] 

% // Normal
```

[image]

As you can see it starts with the first date in opposition to rounded example you gave. Don't know how to specify the window start automatically except of adding artificial date at the beginning.

You may also be interested in [HistogramList for DateHistogram?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123607/5478)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the most efficient, but it's convenient and kinda concise:

```
In[72]:= times = Normal@KeyMap[TimeObject, date];
Map[First@First@# -> Total@Map[Last, #] &,
 Block[{time = First@First@times},
  SplitBy[times,
   If[First[#] - time > Quantity[3, "Minutes"],
     time = First[#];
     True,
     False
     ] &
   ]
  ]
 ]

Out[73]= {TimeObject[{8, 0, 10.}, TimeZone -> -4.] -> 178, 
 TimeObject[{8, 3, 12.}, TimeZone -> -4.] -> 211, 
 TimeObject[{8, 6, 14.}, TimeZone -> -4.] -> 217, 
 TimeObject[{8, 9, 17.}, TimeZone -> -4.] -> 237, 
 TimeObject[{8, 12, 18.}, TimeZone -> -4.] -> 157}
```

Comment: Since every three minutes,it should give some result of 08:00,08:03,08:06,08:09,08:12,08:14. :)